Added Articles Are Being Ignored
there is a publisher --> distributor --> subscriber setup and all has been well configured in this system and a few simple tests of adding a few tables and re-snapping tables seems to work well.
The problem is we have over 6K articles per database and many databases in a multi-tenant system. The system has been in operation for over 20 years and almost all databases has picked up heaps and un-compile-able views or stored procedures. We can't point and click each time a database is restored and/or needs to be re/published; therefore, the following is being tested.
I understand this can be scripted, but we are following this advice for re-snapping tables.
The initial test

Create the subscription with 1 article tblAccountingBatch.
Run the script bellow to add all tables with a PK and all compliable articles.
Re-run the snapshot agent and pick up the new tables.

The Results

The UI shows all ~5K articles are active and selected in sub.
The snapshot runs and generates 1 article for the initial table, tblAccountingBatch.
EXEC sp_helpsubscription show only one table - tblAccountingBatch.
I try to script out addding another that is ticked in the UI using sp_addarticle and get an error that the article has already been added.

Does anywhere know where the disconnect could be. The snapshot does not seem to see the articles added after the sub was created.
I came across this KB which describes something very similar; however, the DBA says these patches have been applied in the test environments.
Script to Add All Valid Articles After Subscription is Created
SET NOCOUNT ON

USE VP_UPS_V05
GO

DECLARE @PublicationName NVARCHAR(200) = 'UPS_PUB'

EXEC sp_changepublication @publication = @PublicationName, @property = 'allow_anonymous' , @value = 'false' 
EXEC sp_changepublication @publication = @PublicationName, @property = 'immediate_sync' , @value = 'false' 


IF(CHARINDEX('VP_',DB_NAME()) = 0 OR CHARINDEX('_V05',DB_NAME()) =0 ) BEGIN
    RAISERROR('This script can only be applied against a Client database', 16, 1)
    RETURN
END


DECLARE @Debug BIT = 0

DECLARE @FullName nvarchar(1000);
DECLARE @ShortName nvarchar(300)
DECLARE @ObjectType nvarchar(300)
DECLARE @HasPrimaryKey BIT
DECLARE @Sql nvarchar(1000);
DECLARE @Result int;


DECLARE @Exceptions TABLE(ShortName NVARCHAR(300), FullName NVARCHAR(300),ObjectType NVARCHAR(300), Result INT, ErrorMessage NVARCHAR(MAX))


DECLARE @IgnoredTables TABLE (TableName NVARCHAR(100))
INSERT INTO @IgnoredTables VALUES
    ('tblAccountingBatch')
    

DECLARE ObjectCursor CURSOR FOR
SELECT 
    ShortName,LongName,ObjectType,HasPrimaryKey
FROM
(
    SELECT  
        OBJECT_NAME(o.object_id) ShortName , 
        QUOTENAME(SCHEMA_NAME(o.schema_id)) + '.' + QUOTENAME(OBJECT_NAME(o.object_id)) LongName, 
        CASE WHEN type_desc = 'USER_TABLE' THEN CASE WHEN  OBJECTPROPERTY(o.object_id,'tablehasprimaryKey') = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ELSE 0 END AS HasPrimaryKey,
        type_desc AS ObjectType,
        CASE 
            WHEN type_desc='USER_TABLE' THEN 0
            WHEN type_desc='VIEW' THEN 1 
            WHEN type_desc='SQL_SCALAR_FUNCTION' THEN 2
            WHEN type_desc='SQL_TABLE_VALUED_FUNCTION' THEN 3
            WHEN type_desc='SQL_INLINE_TABLE_VALUED_FUNCTION' THEN 4
            WHEN type_desc='SQL_TRIGGER' THEN 5
            WHEN type_desc='SQL_STORED_PROCEDURE' THEN 6
            ELSE
                7
        END AS ProcessOrder
    FROM 
        sys.objects o
        LEFT OUTER JOIN @IgnoredTables IgnoredTable ON type_desc = 'USER_TABLE' AND IgnoredTable.TableName = OBJECT_NAME(o.object_id)
    WHERE 
        type_desc IN ('USER_TABLE','SQL_STORED_PROCEDURE','SQL_TRIGGER','SQL_SCALAR_FUNCTION','SQL_TABLE_VALUED_FUNCTION','SQL_INLINE_TABLE_VALUED_FUNCTION','VIEW')    
        AND 
        ISNULL(OBJECTPROPERTY(o.object_id, 'IsSchemaBound'), 0) = 0
        AND
        SCHEMA_NAME(o.schema_id)='dbo'
        AND
        IgnoredTable.TableName IS NULL
        AND
        ((type_desc = 'USER_TABLE' AND OBJECT_NAME(o.object_id) LIKE 'tbl%')OR(type_desc<>'USER_TABLE'))
)AS X 
Order BY ProcessOrder, ShortName;

--RETURN

OPEN ObjectCursor;

DECLARE @TotalObjects INT = @@CURSOR_ROWS
DECLARE @CurrentObject INT = 0

FETCH NEXT FROM ObjectCursor INTO @ShortName, @FullName, @ObjectType, @HasPrimaryKey

DECLARE @IsError BIT = 0
DECLARE @CompileResult BIT = 0
DECLARE @ErrorMessage NVARCHAR(MAX)

DECLARE @InsertCommand NVARCHAR(300)
DECLARE @DeleteCommand NVARCHAR(300)
DECLARE @UpdateCommand NVARCHAR(300)
DECLARE @ArticleType NVARCHAR(300)

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    SET @CurrentObject = @CurrentObject + 1
    PRINT 'Processing Object '+CAST(@CurrentObject AS VARCHAR(10))+'/'+CAST(@TotalObjects AS VARCHAR(10))+' - '+@ObjectType+' '+@ShortName
     
    SET @IsError = 0
    SET @ErrorMessage = ''

    IF(@ObjectType = 'USER_TABLE') BEGIN 
        IF(@HasPrimaryKey = 0 ) BEGIN
            SET @IsError = 1
            SET @ErrorMessage = 'Missing Primary Key'   
        END     
    END ELSE BEGIN      
        SET @Sql = N'EXEC sp_refreshsqlmodule ''' + @FullName + '''';       
        BEGIN TRY
            EXEC @CompileResult = sp_executesql @Sql;
            IF @CompileResult <> 0 RAISERROR('Failed', 16, 1);
        END TRY
        BEGIN CATCH
            SET @IsError = 1
            SET @ErrorMessage = ERROR_MESSAGE()             
        END CATCH
    END

    IF(@IsError = 0 AND @Debug=0) BEGIN
        BEGIN TRY           
            IF(@ObjectType = 'USER_TABLE') BEGIN

                SET @InsertCommand = 'CALL sp_MSins_dbo_'+@ShortName
                SET @DeleteCommand = 'CALL sp_MSdel_dbo_'+@ShortName
                SET @UpdateCommand = 'CALL sp_MSupd_dbo_'+@ShortName

                exec sp_addarticle 
                    @publication = @PublicationName, 
                    @article = @ShortName, 
                    @source_owner = 'dbo', 
                    @source_object = @ShortName, 
                    @type = 'logbased', 
                    @description = null, 
                    @creation_script = null, 
                    @pre_creation_cmd = 'drop', 
                    @schema_option = 0x000000000803509F, 
                    @identityrangemanagementoption = 'manual', 
                    @destination_table = @ShortName, 
                    @destination_owner = 'dbo', 
                    @vertical_partition = 'false', 
                    @ins_cmd = @InsertCommand, 
                    @del_cmd = @DeleteCommand, 
                    @upd_cmd = @UpdateCommand
            END ELSE IF (@ObjectType IN ('SQL_INLINE_TABLE_VALUED_FUNCTION','SQL_SCALAR_FUNCTION','SQL_STORED_PROCEDURE','SQL_TABLE_VALUED_FUNCTION','VIEW')) BEGIN
                IF(@ObjectType='SQL_STORED_PROCEDURE') 
                    SET @ArticleType = 'proc schema only'
                ELSE IF(@ObjectType = 'VIEW')   
                    SET @ArticleType = 'view schema only'
                ELSE
                    SET @ArticleType ='func schema only'
                    
                exec sp_addarticle 
                    @publication =@PublicationName, 
                    @article = @ShortName, 
                    @source_owner = 'dbo', 
                    @source_object = @ShortName, 
                    @type = @ArticleType, 
                    @description = null, 
                    @creation_script = null, 
                    @pre_creation_cmd = N'drop', 
                    @schema_option = 0x0000000008000001, 
                    @destination_table = @ShortName, 
                    @destination_owner = 'dbo'

            END
        END TRY
        BEGIN CATCH
            SET @IsError = 1
            SET @ErrorMessage = 'Could Not Add Article to Replication - '+ERROR_MESSAGE()  
            IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0 ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
        END CATCH
    END 
    
    IF(@IsError = 1)  
        INSERT INTO @Exceptions SELECT  @ShortName, @FullName, @ObjectType, 0, @ErrorMessage
        
    FETCH NEXT FROM ObjectCursor INTO @ShortName, @FullName, @ObjectType, @HasPrimaryKey
END

CLOSE ObjectCursor;
DEALLOCATE ObjectCursor; 

SELECT * FROM @Exceptions


Do you see all of these Articles selected in the Publication's Properties UI? 5,000 Articles is kind of a lot. Do you see any messages or errors in the Agent Status windows?

Agree 100%. The idea was to start with everything and work backwards. Thinking to go with just tables. The UI showed all articles selected, however, in the case above I could not get a snapshot out with anything but the one selected during the first snapshot. This could be my unfamiliarity with UI timing. When I created an empty pub and scripted all tables, that went through after some time. I am going to create a new table and try the method above, making options change, adding the new table to selected articles and see if the subs pick up on a smaller snapshot. This could be user error.

Answering this myself. I've found many variations related to this. In my case it boils down to the fact that I was not running a trace while adding articles in the UI. I found a post that states that a call to sp_refreshsubscriptions is warranted sometimes. That is what I missed.
From observations, and please correct me if I am wrong, the first snapshot just needs:
EXEC sp_reinitsubscription 
    @subscriber = @SubServer,
    @destination_db = @SubDB,
    @publication = @PubName,
    @invalidate_snapshot=1

EXEC sp_startpublication_snapshot
     @publication = @PubName

After that, articles added using the allow_anonymous and immediate_sync just need a :
sp_refreshsubscriptions
sp_startpublication_snapshot

